# How can i get the date formate "11, jul,Tue " in java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, datetimepicker

i want to select the date format from calendar which display date as "11 Jul,Tue " in java. How can i get convert date into this format.

Comment: you can use format as   "d, MMM, EEE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `SimpleDateFormat` class to get what you want. You can use a format of `"dd, MMM, EEE"` The `dd` gives you the day as a number; the `MMM` the month; and the `EEE` the day as text. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the Ocacle documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`

So it would work as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM, EEE");
System.out.println(sdf.format( new Date()) );
```

That would print out the current date as `11, Jul, Tue` You can get your `Date` object from the `Calender` using `getTime()` So:

```
Calender yourCalenderObject;
Date date = yourCalenderObject.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM, EEE");
System.out.println( sdf.format(date) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format date into string that way.

```
    String pattern = "dd, MMM, EEE";
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).format(LocalDateTime.now())); // java 8
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(new Date()));   // java 7 and lower
```